# Declaration file for extended prototype

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function called `foo` defined in a "util.ts" file and I add it to the `String` prototype like this:

```
if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype).indexOf("foo") == -1) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "foo", { value: method, enumerable: false });
}
```

The issue is that if I generate ".d.ts" file automatically with "tsc", this function won't be marked as a method of the `String` prototype, so I won't be able to use it in "TypeScript" like this:

```
import { foo } from "..."

let str: string = "Foo";

str.foo();
```

Is there of way of achieve that without manually creating the ".d.ts" (I actually don't even know how to achieve that manually).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your `utils.ts` should do the trick:

```
declare global
{
    interface String
    {
        foo(): string;
    }
}

(String.prototype as any).foo= function () { return "FOO"; }
```

Keep in mind that this is potentially [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) though.

Comment: Thanks. However, as I'm creating a small framework (utility function), I'll that your advice int account and won't extend already existing prototype. Thanks ;-)